# Only do wiring along the x/y axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circuitikz

[image]

Is there a way to draw a wire only along the x or y axis?
I mean of course you can do it manually when you give it fixed points, but is there a way to give two coordinates and latex splits it up in two paths.
The red line is the way i want it to go.

When there is not a automatic way to do it, i have an idea to solve the problem:
I use the same idea of spliting up the way in two seperate paths and i only feed the first path with the x distance and the second path with the y distance.
Like this:

```
\draw (A) to [short] ++ ("B.x - A.x",0) to [short] ++ (0 , "B.y-A.y");
```

My problem here is, that i cannot figure out a way to only get the x/y coordinate of a node. "(A.x)" is just placeholder for the x coordinate of the A node.
Is there a command for getting a coordinate of a node.

In this trivial example i could go back to my definition of the node and just read the coordinates and do the wiring manually, but when you dont know the positon, it isnt that easy.
For example when you are working with mosfets and want to connect to the mosfet.gate node.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[european, very thick, scale=5, transform shape]
    % Points
    \draw (0,0) node[circ](A){};
    \draw (1,-1) node[circ](B){};
    %Lables
    \draw (A) node[anchor = east] {A};
    \draw (B) node[anchor = west] {B};
    %Direct Path
    \draw (A) to [short] (B);
    %Path along axis
    \draw[red] (A) to [short] (1,0) to [short] (B);

    %Idea
    %\draw (A) to [short] ++ (B.x - A.x ,0) to [short] ++ (0 , B.y-A.y);  
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can also use `(A-|B)` for the midpoint, but it still takes two `to[short]`s.  Then I only use `to[short]` to add things like [*-o].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has a syntax for this: instead of using `to`, you can use `|-` or `-|`. For more details see section 14.2.2 of the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), page 156.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[european, very thick, scale=5, transform shape]
    % Points
    \draw (0,0) node[circ](A){};
    \draw (1,-1) node[circ](B){};
    %Lables
    \draw (A) node[anchor = east] {A};
    \draw (B) node[anchor = west] {B};
    %Direct Path
    \draw (A) to [short] (B);
    %Path along axis
    \draw[red] (A) -| (B);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

- `circuitikz` is based on `tikz`, so in schemas drawing by it you can use `tikz` syntax for drawing of lines
- as stated in nice @wincent answer, for what you after `tikz` provide macro, which draw straight lines that are only horizontal and vertical: `-|` for first horizontal and than vertical and `|-` for first vertical and than horizontal)
- probably the shortest way how to draw what you after is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[european, very thick, scale=5, transform shape]
\draw   (0, 0) node[circ, label=west:A] {} -|
        (1,-1) node[circ, label=east:B] {};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]